# Swift Mailer : Address in mailbox given [] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2

Tags: swiftmailer

I have a little problem here, when I try to send an email using swiftmailer, I got an error.

Here's my code:

```
<?php

session_start();
include("config.php");
$dir = dirname(__FILE__);
$session = $_SESSION[serialize];

// Load the SwiftMailer files
        require_once($dir.'/swift/swift_required.php');

$hold = 'TIDAK';
// Kondisi - Kondisi yang ada
if($_GET[phase]=='confirm'){
        $to = "test@127.0.0.1";
        $kalimat = "Invoice Dengan nomor ".$_GET[nosc]." Telah di confirm, mohon di cek di sistem";
        $kalimat2 = "Berikut terlampir data Invoice Customer , mohon di pastikan.";
        $title = "CONFIRMATION NOTIFICATION";

}                

                // Convert string dlu



        $mailer = new Swift_Mailer(new Swift_MailTransport()); // Create new instance of SwiftMailer
                $message = Swift_Message::newInstance()
                                           ->setSubject($title) // Message subject
                       ->setTo(array($to)) // Array of people to send to
                       ->setBcc(array($bcc)) // Bcc:
                                           ->setFrom(array($_SESSION[mailadmin] => $_SESSION[namauser].''.store('namasite'))) // From:
                                           ->setBody($kalimat, 'text/html'); // Attach that HTML message from earlier



        // Send the email, and show user message
                if($hold<>'YA'){
                    if ($mailer->send($message)){
            echo json_encode(array('success'=>true));
                    } else {
            echo json_encode(array('success'=>false));
                    }
                }
?>
```

And then when I try to post the data to this file through jquery I got an error, this error I got from firebug.

```
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'Swift_RfcComplianceException' with message 'Address in mailbox given [] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2.' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Colosus\core\swift\classes\Swift\Mime\Headers\MailboxHeader.php:319
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Colosus\core\swift\classes\Swift\Mime\Headers\MailboxHeader.php(249): Swift_Mime_Headers_MailboxHeader-&gt;_assertValidAddress(NULL)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Colosus\core\swift\classes\Swift\Mime\Headers\MailboxHeader.php(107): Swift_Mime_Headers_MailboxHeader-&gt;normalizeMailboxes(Array)
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\Colosus\core\swift\classes\Swift\Mime\Headers\MailboxHeader.php(71): Swift_Mime_Headers_MailboxHeader-&gt;setNameAddresses(Array)
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\Colosus\core\swift\classes\Swift\Mime\SimpleHeaderFactory.php(74): Swift_Mime_Headers_MailboxHeader-&gt;setFieldBodyModel(Array)
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\Colosus\core\swift\classes\Swift\Mime\SimpleHeaderSet.php(87): Swift_Mime_SimpleHeaderFactory-&gt;createMailboxHeader('Bcc', Array)
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\Colosus\core\swift\classes\Swift\Mime in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\Colosus\core\swift\classes\Swift\Mime\Headers\MailboxHeader.php</b> on line <b>319</b><br />
```

So guys, anybody can help me here? I really doesn't know what happening here.

Answer (score 13):

It's better if you use a try/catch around the send instruction:

```
try {
     if ($mailer->send($message)){
        ...
     }

} catch (Exception $e) {
    $log_error->write_error($e->getMessage() . ';');
}
```

Or if you validate the email before sending it:

```
if(!Swift_Validate::email($email)){ //if email is not valid
                //do something, skip them or log them
                $log_error->log($email);
}
```

Comment: Good tip with that Swift_Validate --

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure there is no white space before or after the email address given.